# How to make custom bootstrap tabs justified

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, react-bootstrap

I am using React-Bootstrap for my tabs. I am using the lower level configuration so I can modify the css. I have everything the way I want it but I can not figure out how to make the tabs justified. I have looked at the bootstrap css file but I cannot make it work. What do I need to add?

Thanks

```
 .nav-tabs {
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
.nav-tabs>li {
    // color: $text-color;
}
.nav-tabs>li>a,
.nav-tabs>li>a {
    padding: 0px 24px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0;
    // border-bottom: 2px solid;
    color: inherit;
    &:hover,
    &:focus {
        border-bottom-color: rgba($gray-base, .36);
        background-color: transparent;
        color: inherit;
    }
}
.nav-tabs>li>a {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    border-bottom-color: rgba($gray-base, .16);
}
.nav-tabs>li.active {
    color: $brand-primary;
}
.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover,
.nav-tabs>.active>a,
.nav-tabs>.active>a:hover,
.nav-tabs>.active>a:focus {
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    color: inherit;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.tab-content {
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

Comment: what kind of justification you need ? left right ?

Comment: 100% width for each tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a style in your css files as below.

```
.justify {
flex:1;
}
```

then use  inline style property as below

```
<Tabs defaultActiveKey="profile" id="uncontrolled-tab-example" style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'space-between',flexDirection:'row'}}>
  <Tab eventKey="home" title="Home"  tabClassName={Styles.justify}>
    {/* <Sonnet /> */}
  </Tab>
  <Tab eventKey="profile" title="Profile" tabClassName={Styles.justify}>
    {/* <Sonnet /> */}
  </Tab>
  <Tab eventKey="contact" title="Contact" tabClassName={Styles.justify} >
    {/* <Sonnet /> */}
  </Tab>
</Tabs>
```